# htaccess : how to transform the url hello/ola/ciao/register.php to u/u/u/page.php?

Tags: .htaccess

I have read a some post and apache documentation on this topic.

I want to transform the url `hello/ola/ciao/page.php` to  `u/u/u/page.php` to hide the website logic.

If I write:

```
RewriteRule ^hello/ola/ciao/(.*)$  u/u/u/$1  [R]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^hello/ola/ciao/(.*)$  u/u/u/$1  [P]
```

it returns the message:

```
The requested URL /u/u/u/page.php was not found on this server
```

MY HTTPD.CONF is :

```
<Directory "C:/workspace">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Therefore I do not want redirect to `u/u/u/page.php` because `u/u/u/` folders do not exist on the server.

I only want to transform the url to `u/u/u/page.php`, make it nicer.

- Is it possible to obtain this result?
- Is it possible rewrite url without redirect it?
- I must to use .htaccess,RewriteRule P flag,ProxyPassReverse or PHP script?
- What apache modules must to be enabled?
- Which folder it needs to be put the .htaccess? In the root folder or
  subfolder too?
- It works in hoster web space or on localhost too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^u/u/u/(.*).php$ hello/ola/ciao/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I type in browser's address bar http://localhost/hello/ola/ciao/page.php
and nothing happens.
I see the webpage page.php

Comment: does u/u/u/page.php exist?

Comment: u/u/u/page.php not exist, hello/ola/ciao/page.php exist.

if i type http://localhost/u/u/u/page.php i see http://localhost/hello/ola/ciao/page.php

If i type http://localhost/hello/ola/ciao/page.php i see http://localhost/hello/ola/ciao/page.php
It works typing http://localhost/u/u/u/page.php !

Is it possible type http://localhost/hello/ola/ciao/page.php and to see http://localhost/u/u/u/page.php ?

Comment: so what i get is you want to rewrite `u/u/u/page.php` to `hello/ola/ciao/$1.php` or is other way around?

Comment: is other way around.

I want to rewrite  hello/ola/ciao/$1.php to u/u/u/page.php.
that is i want to type hello/ola/ciao/$1.php and to see the url u/u/u/page.php.

u/u/u/page.php not exist

Comment: that is what i am doing you want to show `u/u/u/page.php` on browser and  fetch `hello/ola/ciao/page.php` that is what this wil do please check!

Comment: I want to show u/u/u/page.php on browser and fetch hello/ola/ciao/page.php, it's right

but i want to type in address bar hello/ola/ciao/page.php not u/u/u/page.php

Comment: Well the same goes. Thank you